# GitHub API Quota with Jenkins and Webhooks

Tags: jenkins, github, github-webhook

Wondering if there are any suggestions to work around the API quota of 5000 from GitHub, particularly around Jenkins usage.

For context, we have ~300 repos and ~100 GitHub users. We initially had most jobs do org/repo scans, and as we started to get more things running on Jenkins, began to consistently exceed quota. We reduced the frequency of the scans, but the problem still remained.

We then implemented webhooks, but found that the webhooks didn't actually trigger the appropriate jobs, but rather served as a trigger for the repo scans. During off-peak hours, this is definitely better than scans, but during the day can be potentially worse.

Question is: how to do other folks work through this issue? Is there something we're missing with our setup? Or should we just drop the notion of Git events triggering jobs in jenkins almost immediately?

Comment: find any good solutions?

Comment: unfortunately not :(